# Magento 301 problem - magento is making 2 redirects but I need only 1 - V1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I have an install of Magento V1.7 that has several languages / stores etc.

The structure of the site has been continually changing and as such lots of 301s have been created.

I now have the problem that on some of my category pages there are 2 active 301 redirects in place which our SEO guy is saying is a bad idea.

As an example I have a category for football goals and the original URL was: **quickplaysport.com/fr/buts-et-mini-buts**

now we have changed it so the french store is on the french domain quickplaysport.fr and the actual category URL has changed from **buts-et-mini-buts** to **cage-but-mini-but-football**.

This means that it is doing a 301 redirect from anything at .com/fr/***** to .fr/***** and then doing a second redirect from **quickplaysport.fr/buts-et-mini-buts** to **quickplaysport.fr/cage-but-mini-but-football**.

Can anyone tell me how I should be setting up the 301's correctly so it goes from **quickplaysport.com/fr/buts-et-mini-buts** to **quickplaysport.fr/cage-but-mini-but-football**. With just the 1 redirect?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a server level rewrite for .com/fr/* to .fr/* ? Or are you using the magento url rewrites to accomplish that?

Comment: I have an .htaccess file within a subfolder /fr/ which has the following lines in it:

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.quickplaysport\.fr 
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.quickplaysport.fr/$1 [R=301,L]

Its my understanding that this means anyone who goes to the subfolder will be redirected to the equivalent page on the .fr domain. It is in the subfolder as we used to have the different stores in subfolders such as /fr/ /de/ etc and so need to 301 all the indexed URLs to the new structure.

Comment: I have then set the base URL for the French site to quickplaysport.fr within the backend of Magento.

I do not have access to the Vhosts file so I  think my method is basically using Magentos 301s

Answer (score 0):

This is more a server configuration question based on the comments made, but with your setup you would really need to alter the .htaccess file to manually target the individual URLS.

Example:

```
Redirect 301 /fr/your-url.html http://www.example.fr/your-url.html
```

This will cause all requests to your fr/your-url.html product to redirect directly to the example.fr/your-url.html file instead. At this point it reaches the final destination. What'll be happening with your current setup is your hitting the old url from before the redirect, then being redirected to the new one within Magento hence the two URL Rewrites.

You can keep the current general rule to cover any individual rewrites that you have potentially missed out on.

Comment: Thanks, should I be adding this to the .htaccess file in the Magento root or the one in my subfolder (/fr/)?

Comment: You will want to put it into the webroot .htaccess, or alternatively have your ISP put it in the server configuration.

Comment: I just tried it in the root htaccess file and it doesnt work. its as if the other redirect is taking priority and it only swaps the .com/fr to .fr. this is the line I added:     Redirect 301 /fr/buts-et-mini-buts.html http://www.quickplaysport.fr/cage-but-mini-but-football.html I have tried it with and without the .html suffix but no joy

Comment: I think the order will be important - Redirect first then the general rewrite rule will kick in.